# TypeScript & React useEffect -- This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof React' has no call signatures TS2349

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

In the following code, I am getting the TypeScript error:

```
This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof React' has no call signatures TS2349
```

In what way do I need to declare the type? Appreciate the help as I get used to TypeScript in React.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // subscribe to some data source
    console.log('subscribe to some data source');
    return () => {
        // unsubscribe to avoid memory leak
        console.log('this will run when the component unmounts');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**useEffect** is not default export from react.

You need import as not default export  like this:

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I imported React as follows

```
import * as React from "react";
```

I needed to prefix the useEffect hook with React as such:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `useEffect` hook should be called inside the body of a functional component. It cannot be called directly outside of a component declaration.
2. Also, make sure that useEffect is imported from `'react'` library:

`import React, { useEffect } from 'react';`

The sample code below should work as expected:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const YourComponent: React.FC = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // This function will run when the component mounts

    // Perform some side effects or subscribe to a data source
    console.log('Subscribe to some data source');

    return () => {
      // This function will run when the component unmounts

      // Cleanup or unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks
      console.log('This will run when the component unmounts');
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    // JSX for your component
    <div>Component content</div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```